# java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: on varchar field while doing jpa repository.save()

Tags: java, hibernate

MerchantConfig entity -

```
public class MerchantConfig {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private Long entityId;
    private String entityType;
    ..
}


  merchantConfig = new MerchantConfig();
         
  merchantConfig.setEntityType(Enum.MerchantConfigType.MERCHANT_ID.v);
  merchantConfigRespository.save(merchantConfig); //exception is thrown here, if  .setEntityType() is done.
```

Debug output of merchantConfig at this point -
[image]

Enum definition -

```
public enum MerchantConfigType {
    MERCHANT_ID("merchant_id"),
    USER_ID("user_id");

    public final String v;

    MerchantConfigType(String value) {
        this.v = value;
    }
}
```

I am not sure why it says incorrect integer value? It is a varchar auto-generated by Hibernate entity definition which is String, for this field.

**Update**

Table schema - partial -

```
 CREATE TABLE `MerchantConfig` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `entityId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `entityType` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `merchantId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=32 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**Exception**

```
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
.. 
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: 'merchant_id' for column 'entityType' at row 1
```

**Update 2**

Hibernate auto creation log -

Hibernate:

```
create table MerchantConfig (
   id bigint not null auto_increment,
    entityId bigint,
    entityType varchar(255)
  ) engine=InnoDB
```

Comment: Is the `memberId` expected to be null?

Comment: Yes. `entityType` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, `merchantId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL

Comment: Ok, which field exactly is throwing that exception?  My hunch is it's merchant id

Comment: No, it is the entityType. Oh I added the exception now.

Answer (score 0):

I have meet the same problem before.
in springBoot database configuration File, add followd string after datasource url：

```
?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
```

At least your string code transformation will not be wrong.